# How does a malware differentiate between a real user device from a sandbox?

Tags: malware, sandbox

I'm currently working on malware evasions. As far as I know, malware can tell sandboxes from real user devices by examining device characteristics like wear and tear, looking for human-like behavior or making generic OS queries.

What are the most common features that malware checks to decide whether the environment is a sandbox or a real-user device?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can ransomware detect Virtual Environments?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/233432/can-ransomware-detect-virtual-environments), [Malware sandbox detection](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/172372/malware-sandbox-detection).

Comment: What research effort have you done?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=What+are+the+most+common+features+that+malware+checks+to+decide+whether+the+environment+is+a+sandbox